# C++ Two templates, same name, same signatures, different classes: How to force compiler to use intended one?

Tags: c++

I am trying to use the following C++ template:

```
    _CONSTEXPR20 void swap(_Ty& _Left, _Ty& _Right) noexcept(
    is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<_Ty>&& is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<_Ty>) {
    _Ty _Tmp = _STD move(_Left);
    _Left    = _STD move(_Right);
    _Right   = _STD move(_Tmp);
}
```

from the Microsoft utility standard header (core), but the compiler keeps using the following template:

```
inline void swap(thread& _Left, thread& _Right) noexcept {
    _Left.swap(_Right);
}
```

from the Microsoft thread standard header.

How to force the compiler to use the first implementation?

Comment: First question would be, are you swapping `thread` objects? Because if you are, the specific type is always going to beat a template or auto type.

Comment: Are you dealing with `std::thread` objects? Please post a small code sample that calls the undesirable overload instead of the one you want? Though be warned, for threads, this *is* the intended function.

Comment: How are you trying it? Please post a [mcve]. Also explain why you want to use one and not the other.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the new details. also provide the full template for what you want to be used

Comment: Thanks everyone for your prompt reply. 

The code that I am trying to implement is as follows: 

template<typename T> static void reset_vector_to_default(T& value) { std::swap(T(), value); }

And I am trying to use it: SupportingMethods:

reset_vector_to_default(wd); 

Where wd: 

std::vector<Date> Sql::wd; // vector with all the working days for the next 10 years (default value) 

And yes I include <thread>, for I use some thread functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the compiler will prefer a non-template overload of a function over one that is a template.

If you need to use the template version, just pass the type argument explicitly:

```cpp
swap<std::thread>(thread1, thread2);
```